# Show combined diff from selected git commits

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repository with a lot of changes. I want to review changes related to particular issue. Those commits are already in the master branch and are interleaved with unrelated commits. I can identify those interesting commits via specific text in their message. I can also see the individual changes with `git diff` command. However, I would like to see them as single patch: If first commit changed some lines and the second one changed them again, I do not want to see the interim state. I also do not want to see any changes from unrelated commits (unless necessary to resolve conflicts).

The only way to achieve this I can think of, is to update the whole tree to the state before first commit. Apply the changes one after another and then `git diff` working directory against base revision.

However, this won't work, if included commits depend on not-included commits. Instead of failing or having to manually resolve conflicts, I would prefer to just include necessary changes from other commits. The output will be read only by humans, so as long as all the relevant changes are included, I don't care how the conflicts are handled.

It would also be nice, if I didn't have to stash my local changes before this operation.

How to avoid those problems and generate such patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program called `combinediff` which should be able to do this; make a diff for each change you care about, then feed them all to `combinediff`. It's part of the `patchutils` package, which on Linux is typically available via your distribution's package manager. The source is located at https://github.com/twaugh/patchutils.